# Parse Phonegap Return to App when Push Arrive

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, parse-platform

I want to know how to return to my app, when she is on the background.

I'm using Android and Phonegap, I need that my app return to his actual moment when I click on the Push Notification that I receive, but with this,  *PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, Main.class);*

My app only restart all over, and my app has a Log In so, everytime that a Push is receive, I need to Log In again, and I lose the action that I need to do in my HTML page.

Someone have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: I'm currently trying to solve this one myself, so this is not an answer... yet... but I believe it is necessary to respond with an `Intent` rather than an `Activity` ([see here](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#receiving-responding/Android)). I'm not too familiar with Android myself, so I'm still trying to figure all this out, but if I have some success I'll post my findings here.